# How to create a class which is to be de-serialized from XML

Tags: c#, xml

How to create a C# class which must be used to deserialize the XML as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML>
    <StatusCode>-2</StatusCode>
    <Warnings />
    <Errors>
        <Error> Debtor #2 Invalid Postal Code</Error>
        <Error>Invalid lien term</Error>
    </Errors>
</XML>
```

Comment: What have you tried? btw, the `<Warnings />` tag suggests a collection of warnings exists, but it might be empty.

Comment: <Warnings/> were also similar to <Errors/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML));
            XML xml = (XML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, xml);
        }
    }
    public class XML
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Warnings { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Errors")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Error")]
        public List<string> errors { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create classes based on XML, copy the xml to the clipboard, then in Visual Studio 2017, choose the menu option: Edit/Paste Special/Paste XML as classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class should look like:

```
public class ErrorClass
{
    struct Error
    {
        public String message;
    }
    struct Warning
    {
        public String message;
    }

    int StatusCode;
    List<Error> Errors;
    List<Warning> Warnings;

}
```

Error and Warning struct could contain more items that are not used in the example you posted.